# Getting "The parameter app_id is required" with OAuth.io

Tags: oauth.io

I am trying to integrate https://oauth.io/ into my application. Below is the code for facebook integration that I am using:

```
 OAuth.popup('facebook')
            .done(function (result) {
                alert('sucess');
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                alert('fail');
            });
```

Note: I am calling the above part of code in a button click.

In JQuery ready function I am calling `OAuth.initialize("my_public_key");`

When I click on the button I am getting "The parameter app_id is required" error in the popup. (added image of it)

[image]

Can someone let me know If I am missing something.

Comment: check app_id in your https://oauth.io/ configuration setting.

Comment: Sorry to ask... But I am not seeing any config file for oauth. Can you let me know if this is something that we should be adding??

Comment: https://oauth.io/  is third party? then you must add your app_id in https://oauth.io/  configuration setting.

Comment: Yes its a third party. I have used https://oauth.io/home site. I just took oauth.js file that they asked to include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must Integrate APIs in OAuth, follow the below method.

1. Login to your account.
2. Then click on the `Integrated APIs` menu from the left side bar.
3. Now click on `ADD APIs` green button on the right top corner.
4. Now Search and select Facebook.
5. Now add the `Keys and Permission Scope` details and others.

Comment: I am seeing clientId, client_Secret and scope there. What are these? Can you help me regarding them?

Comment: Click here to see where to get your keys on Facebook: ? click on `?` you will find.

Comment: I got the required keys but still I am facing some error while opening popup. I am getting 'Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.....' message. I am using http://localhost:17136/ and have the 'site URL' of facebook.

Comment: Go to Facebook Application setting and add there website url. as in this image. https://oauth.io/api/providers/facebook/keys.png

Comment: Yes it worked out. I thought URL should be the one that is accesssing it( I thought its my site rather its indirectly oauth site).